# Setting up an AnimationListener for an ObjectAnimator

Tags: java, android

In my program, I have an ObjectAnimator which moves an ImageView from left to right. I am trying to set up a listener which will execute a task when the ObjectAnimator is finished running. Here is the relevant section of code which I am currently using to try to accomplish this:

```
  if (num == 350) {
        nAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(gamePiece, "translationX", 0, num);
        nAnim.setDuration(2125);
        nAnim.start();
        nAnim.addListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator a) {
                startGame(level);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator a) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator a) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator a) {

            }

        });
```

When I try to run this in Android Studio, I am getting the error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onAnimationStart() in MainActivity. What do I have to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you implemented AnimatorListener in your MainActivity, you must include all its abstract methods, and change `nAnim.addListener(new Animat....` to `nAnim.addListener(this)`

```
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation){
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){
    startGame(level)
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation){
}

@Override
public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use AnimatorListener class instead of AnimationListener like below

```
nAnim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or switch to Kotlin and put animator.start() as the last line. Offcourse you don't have to implement all animations methods

```
  val gamePiece = Button(this)
    var num = 0
    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(gamePiece, View.TRANSLATION_X, 0f, num.toFloat())
    animator.duration = 2125

    if (num ==350){

        animator.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter(){


          override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation)
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                startGame(level)
            }
        })
    }
    //animator.start() should be the last line
    animator.start()
```